# C pthreads passing local variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written this code to understand how local variables work in a thread. I am passing address of local variable to a thread while creating it from another thread. Once the original thread exits,local variable also gets destroyed as stack frame is destroyed. So what happens in the new thread? Why no segmentation fault?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t t1,t2;
pthread_mutex_t mtx=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* thr_fun2(void *p);


void* thr_fun1(void *p)
{
    int data = 0;
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&t2,0,thr_fun2,&data);
    printf("Thread 1 entered....\n");
    while(1)
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if(data > 5)
        pthread_exit(0);
    printf("thread1:data =%d\n ",data);
    data++;
    sleep(1);
    printf("thread1:data(inc) =%d\n ",data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    sleep(1);
    }


}


void* thr_fun2(void *p)
{
    sleep(1);
    printf("Thread 2 entered....\n");
    while(*(int *)p < 10)
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    printf("thread2:data =%d\n ",*(int *)p);
    (*(int *)p)++;
    sleep(1);
    printf("thread2:data(inc) =%d\n ",*(int *)p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    sleep(1);
    }
}

main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,0);
    pthread_create(&t1,0,thr_fun1,0);
    pthread_join(t1,0);
    pthread_join(t2,0);
//  printf("Back in main fun \n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Thread 1 entered....
thread1:data =0
thread1:data(inc) =1
Thread 2 entered....
thread2:data =1
thread2:data(inc) =2
thread1:data =2
thread1:data(inc) =3
thread2:data =3
thread2:data(inc) =4
thread1:data =4
thread1:data(inc) =5
thread2:data =5
thread2:data(inc) =6
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour...

Comment: Also, make sure that the `t1` was joined before the output from thread2 came?

Comment: Just because the code is wrong doesn't mean that it has to crash.  It may crash; it doesn't have to crash.  You could get various forms of subtle or not so subtle corruption.

Comment: Indentation/formatting:(

Comment: So the conclusion is that the behavior is undefined. If I make 'data' static or declare it globally, it will increment to 10 and terminate. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior. Is this with glibc? There is usually no segmentation fault because glibc keeps a cache of thread stacks, so the memory is not immediately deallocated after thread exit.

Comment: Yes glibc. So it keeps the cache till program termination?

Comment: @Sreena_th_read, no certainly not systematically. If the behavior of a program is undefined, basically anything can happen. In particular, the program may not report an error for all your tests, and then crunch the hard disk of your customer.

Comment: @Sreena_th_read, the thread stack cache is of a fixed size. The stack can be reused for a new thread, and it can be deallocated if more threads are created and terminate.

Answer (score 0):

When data == 6, the thread1 exits, but does not unlock the mutex.
The thread2 remains blocked, waiting for locking the mutex.
So it does not seg-fault. It just deadlocks.

Comment: Hi, I changed it to :
        if(data > 5)
        {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
                pthread_exit(0);
        }

Still same output.